# Spring-AOP related problem: JoinPointMatch was NOT bound in invocation

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop, spring-cloud-stream

I have a springboot + spring cloud streams proyect, there I have some stream listeners configured, and what I want to achieve is, to intercept every incoming message in order to extract a header from it and do something with its value before the message is actually processed. To do that, I've created an AOP advice like follows:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class StreamDyeContextPropagator {

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(listener) && execution(* com.mycompany.subpackage..*(org.springframework.messaging.Message+)) && args(message)", argNames = "listener, message")
    public void streamListener(StreamListener listener, Message<?> message) {
    }

    @Around(value = "streamListener(listener, message)", argNames = "pjp, listener, message")
    public Object retrieveDye(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, StreamListener listener, Message<?> message) throws Throwable {
        // Some logic here
    }
}
```

And following is the spring cloud streams listener code:

```
@EnableBinding(ExchangeRateSink.class)
public class ExchangeRateFromStreamListener {

    @Loggable
    @StreamListener(ExchangeRateSink.NEWEXCHANGERATE)
    public void handle(Message<NewExchangeRateMessage> message) {
        // Some logic here
    }
```

But when I run the project, I get an exception like follows:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required to bind 3
>   arguments, but only bound 1 (JoinPointMatch was NOT bound in
>   invocation)   at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.argBinding(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:605)
>   ...

Any help please?

PS: I know I can use `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` to do something similar, but I want to do it through AOP, and I want to know what's happening here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you need to specify the pointcut in the `@Around` annotation?

Comment: Well, @StreamListener itself results in a proxy, so it's not going to work without getting too deep in the weeds.  `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` is the natural and recommended solution within the context of spring-cloud-stream (SCSt).

Comment: I'm not sure about the fact of @StreamListener resulting in a proxy would prevent it from running, since I have a different aspect to perform logging that is acting on the same method. The point about doing it through aspects is that, as I've just said, another aspect is taking care of logging (of HTTP requests also), and I need this feature to extract a "request unique ID" from incoming messages and adding it to MDC to have it present in every log trace. In this way, if we add it through a channel interceptor, in which order are they going to be executed? I cannot specify that.

Answer (score 3):

I test and find that you can't use `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`, for `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` is usually used for startup initialization.

I suggest you to replace it with `@Order(1).`

Answer (score 2):

Not clear if this is your issue, but it was the problem for me, and this question is the first google result, so I'm posting this as an answer here.

It seems you cannot call `proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()` from anywhere except the method annotated with @Around. You cannot call it from a lambda. You cannot pass it to a method in another class.

I haven't tested, but you might not even be able to pass it to another method in the same class.